# Pymongo: $project fields that are saved in a list

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a python list like this one:

```
Mp_names= ["AA", "BB", "CC" ...]
```

All entries in this list represent field names  that I want to show with $project. So how can I get all my List entries in my MongoDB query so that my Code would theoretically look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(db.MyCollection.aggregate(
       [    
            {"$project" : 
                { 
                "AA": 1,
                "BB": 1,
                "CC": 1
                }

            }         

    ]
)))
```

Comment: have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49672490/6804958) answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary comprehension for that.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(db.MyCollection.aggregate(
       [    
            {
                "$project": {field: 1 for field in Mp_names}
            }         

    ]
)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Oluwafemi Sule! This worked perfectly!

Comment: Do you maybe know how this will look like in a $group tag? So after grouping all fields are shown?

Comment: What fields are you looking to group by?

Comment: The fields I want to group by are not in the list, but after the grouping , it would be great if all fields from the list are shown

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object with this array and pass to `$project` for mongo query.

Something like

```
import json
Mp_names= ["AA", "BB", "CC"]
data = {}
for i in range(len(Mp_names)):
   data[Mp_names[i]] =  1;

 propertiesToShow = json.dumps(data)
```

Now you can use `propertiesToShow` in there. Something like

`{"$project" :  propertiesToShow}`

Comment: Thx for your answer! I tried and got this error: pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: $project specification must be an object